# Performance metrics changing significantly based on batch size

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, overfitting

I am working on a binary classification problem where there is significant class imbalance (minority class makes up nearly 10%). The dataset has ~15,000 observations and I have split this in to a training, validation and test set (that are stratified).

Using PyTorch I build a neural network with 5 fully connected layers (using ReLU activation), CrossEntropyLoss and SGD optimiser. Below is parts of my code

The problem is that my training vs validation loss changes a lot based on batch size (passed in the DataLoader). If I use a batch size of 64, the loss functions look like

[image]

which is quite odd. But if I use an unconventionally large batch size of say 1000, it looks like: [image]

This looks more familiar but I can't make sense of what is going wrong here. I am also seeing that the training set reaches a high recall fairly quickly (after ~4 epochs) while the validation set improves slowly. So there seems to be an issue of overfitting as well.

I don't really know where I am going wrong: my neural network architecture consists of 5 fully connected layers with appropriate input and output dimensions. I initialise the weights. The forward function applies ReLU to the inputs (I don't use Softmax because I only need to classify 0 or 1 so I thought I can simply use argmax, see the 'c' variable in the code above).

I have tried setting Shuffle to true in the training_loader but this produces highly fluctuating training loss values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Batch size is very related to the learning rate, especially in non-adaptive optimizers like the vanilla SGD that you are using.

I would suggest two alternatives:

- Tune (reduce) the learning rate. You can check [the answers to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53033556/674487) for some heuristics on how to choose the value. Apart from that, I recommend the article [*Don't Decay the Learning Rate, Increase the Batch Size*](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=B1Yy1BxCZ).
- Use an adaptive optimizer, like Adam.

Comment: That did it! I changed the learning rate from 0.01 to 0.001 and even 0.0001 and the performance metrics look very reasonable. The same thing when changing to Adam. While I understand the logic behind SGD, Adam is not as clear to me but I will play around with the parameters and try to fine-tune them. Many thanks for the help :)